# react-devtools agent got no connection in react native with expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-debugger

When I'm using [react-native-debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger), **react-devtools doesn't work for me**.

Error Message:

> ```
> DevTools v4 is incompatible with this version of React
> Either upgrade React or install React DevTools v3:
>
> npm install -d react-devtools@^3
> ```

Warning Message:

> react-devtools agent got no connection

I have tried and install npm packages:

- npm install --save-dev react-devtools@^3
- npm install -g react-devtools@^3

How to solve the isseue?

Comment: I was getting the same error, using React Native Debugger (v11), using React Native Debugger (v10) solve my problem. Here's the link from the offical repository: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the good version :

```
brew update && brew cask install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/b6ac3795c1df9f97242481c0817b1165e3e6306a/Casks/react-native-debugger.rb
```

Don't forget to uninstall v4 first (using the same way you install it - npm or brew or...).

---

screenshot from GitHub page:

[image: See screenshot from GitHub page]

Comment: I'm using windows machine

Answer (score 0):

go to this release page: https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/releases

download the file according to your Operating system, then follow the instructions

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger